# How do I make a OneToMany form on Symfony 5?

Tags: php, symfony-forms, symfony5

I'm making a web application where people can see multiple vegetals and their info.
To do so, I have 2 entities in my database : vegetal and leafStructure.
There are 5 other entities but I think only knowing how to do it with one can help.

I want to do a form in vegetal where I can put every info there is and put the structure of the leaves. The problem here is that I have to do this form in VegetalType, because it will be a better UX, but it has a OneToMany relation with every single other entities.

Here is my Vegetal entity :

```
namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\VegetalRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=VegetalRepository::class)
 */
class Vegetal
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Structure::class, mappedBy="vegetal")
     */
    private $structures;

    /**
     * @return Collection|Structure[]
     */
    public function getStructures(): Collection
    {
        return $this->structures;
    }

    public function addStructure(Structure $structure): self
    {
        if (!$this->structures->contains($structure)) {
            $this->structures[] = $structure;
            $structure->setVegetal($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeStructure(Structure $structure): self
    {
        if ($this->structures->removeElement($structure)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($structure->getVegetal() === $this) {
                $structure->setVegetal(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

And here is my vegetalType :

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Vegetal;
use App\Entity\Feuille;
use App\Entity\Famille;


use App\Form\FamilleType;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class VegetalType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('structure', CollectionType::class, array(
                'label'              => 'Structure',
                'translation_domain' => 'forms',
                'entry_type'          => 'App\Form\StructureType',
                'allow_add'          => true,
                'allow_delete'       => true
                    ))


            ->add('enregistrer', SubmitType::class)
        ;
    }


    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'App\Entity\Vegetal',
        ));
    }
}
```

```
namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\StructureRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=StructureRepository::class)
 */
class Structure
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
     */
    private $position;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Vegetal::class, inversedBy="structures")
     */
    private $vegetal;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getPosition(): ?string
    {
        return $this->position;
    }

    public function setPosition(?string $position): self
    {
        $this->position = $position;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getVegetal(): ?Vegetal
    {
        return $this->vegetal;
    }

    public function setVegetal(?Vegetal $vegetal): self
    {
        $this->vegetal = $vegetal;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

If there is some more code you need, I'll gladly show you.

Thank you for your help !

Edit : Here is my StructureType :

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Structure;

use App\Entity\TypeFeuille;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;

class StructureType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('position', TextType::class)
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => 'App\Entity\Structure',
        ]);
    }
}
```

And here is the template (I just took the form part, or else it would have been too long)

```
        {{ form_start(formVegetal) }}

                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row gx-4 gx-lg-5 h-100 align-items-center justify-content-center text-center">   
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 mb-4 form-ajout">

                        <div class="ajoutVegetal" style="display : inline-block;">

                                <h3>Informations générales du végétal</h3>

                                {{ form_row(formVegetal.nom,{'attr' : {'class' : 'form-control'}}  ) }} 

                                {{ form_row(formVegetal.structure,{'attr' : {'class' : 'form-control'}}  ) }} 

                                

                                 </div>            
                                                               
        {{ form_end(formVegetal) }}
```

Comment: What is your question exactly, is this not working?

Comment: @Marleen The problem is that when I try to add a new vegetal, it doesn't show me the field, it just shows me the name of the field but I can't enter a value. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Could you share your StructureType and your template?

Comment: @Marleen Ok, I'll just edit it

Comment: Did you also set up the JavaScript to add new Structure objects to your form? If you're creating a new Vegetal, the form will only display the header "Structure" and no fields, because a new Vegetal object has no Structure objects yet, so there's nothing to display. I think that's what you're seeing? For the JavaScript see: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#adding-and-removing-items

Comment: Also, this field `->add('structure',` should be `->add('structures',`, (plural, as in the Vegetal object).

Comment: Thank you, it works ! I've been looking for an answer so long but now it's done, so thank you !